# type NoneType doesn't define __round__ method

Tags: python, django

I've gone through similar questions but was not able to find a solution to my question. I have 4 cards(movie cards) and the first two are working well but the rest are not. The problem started appearing once I added some logic to views.py in order to show an average rating of each movie based on the reviews given.
**Here is the code in views.py**

```
def detail(request, id):
    movie = Movie.objects.get(id=id)
    reviews = Review.objects.filter(movie=id).order_by('-comment')
    average = reviews.aggregate(Avg('rating'))["rating__avg"]
    average = round(average, 1)
    # The problem is above(in round) but dunno how to fix it

    context = {'movie': movie, 'reviews': reviews,  'average': average}
    return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

Comment: could you include the stack trace? Possible that the first definition for average from your table is None and that would cause round to fail. So perhaps do a check for None types there? Have you checked your data that rating_avg always has a value?

Comment: Your mentioned exception occurs when you try `round(None,1)`. It means your aggregation isn't working. So make sure you are mentioning the right filed in `Avg()`

Comment: [basic links](https://dpaste.com/7YD9ZNAWD).

Comment: @Mubasharjaved  I mentioned the right field in Avg() that's why the first two cards added are working properly but the rest are not...

Comment: Let's have a look at django's [Round function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#round)

Comment: Context for the duplicate: consider `Avg` as equivalent to `Sum` the same solutions apply.

Answer (score -1):

On Superset if you are facing this issue (mapbox chart on Superset), remove the null values for LAt long and the issue would be resolved.

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urLEm.jpg)